# Compile error using orElse after streaming Map to Consumer with super in generic type

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, java-stream, super

I ran into an unexpected compilation error when using the Optional.orElse(..) method. I have a class with a generic type E, and I am trying filter through consumers to find a sufficient one, and use the supplied one if the filtering gives no results. The resulting Consumer will later be used to accept elements of type E. For clarity I have commented out the filter steps.

When using a list of consumers, things work fine:

```
// List of Consumer of super of c: works!
public void listMethod(Consumer<? super E> defaultConsumer) {
    List<Consumer<? super E>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Consumer<? super E> consumer = list.stream()
        //.filter(/*Some filtering which is not relevant*/)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(defaultConsumer);
}
```

However, when using a Map of anything to Consumer, a compile error occurs at orElse:

```
//Map of Object to Consumer of super of C: compile error on orElse
public void mapMethod(Consumer<? super E> defaultConsumer) {
    Map<Object, Consumer<? super E>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Consumer<? super E> consumer = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        //.filter(/*Some filtering which is not relevant*/)
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(defaultConsumer);
}
```

The error message is:

```
The method orElse(Consumer<capture#3-of ? super E>) in the type Optional<Consumer<capture#3-of ? super E>> is not applicable for the arguments (Consumer<capture#6-of ? super E>)
```

Could anyone clarify what is going wrong here? Thanks :)

Edit: This is on jdk1.8.0_45.

Comment: Which Java compiler version? 8u20, 8u45, 9ea99 and Eclipse Luna compile fine the last code sample.

Comment: Interesting how 8u45 works for you. I am using Eclipse Mars, but I also imported it in IntelliJ, and used javac to compile by hand. Both gave the same error.

Comment: Checked again, compiles fine. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/ac2c512a8b6898a7625c) the gist of complete sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of the Eclipse Mars Java compiler.
 
Eclipse has an own compiler and does not use `javac`.

`javac 1.8.0_45` doesn't have a problem on my machine whereas Eclipse Mars shows the error which you have described.

Comment: I've filed a [bugreport](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484960) to eclipse.